# Join variable number of rows in Postgres into json array

Tags: postgresql, json, aggregate

I have the following table:

```
timestamp | type | value | source
----------+------+-------+--------
2020-01-01| 1    | 10    | 2
2020-01-01| 2    | 20    | 2
2020-01-02| 1    | 5     | 4
2020-01-02| 2    | 6     | 3
2020-01-02| 5    | 4     | 3
2020-01-02| 4    | 8     | 1
```

Each `timestamp` + `type` pair is unique. For each `timestamp`, there can be a variable number of rows (but each with a distinct `type`). `value` and `source` are the actual data.

Now I'd like to aggregate by `timestamp` into a json array where, for each timestamp, the available (`type`, `value`, `source`) tuples are included. Ideally, something like:

```
[
  {
    "2020-01-01": [{"type": 1, "value": 10, "source": 2}, {"type": 2, "value": 20, "source": 2}]
  },
  {
    "2020-01-02": [{"type": 1, "value": 5, "source": 4}, {"type": 2, "value": 6, "source": 3}, {"type": 5, "value": 4, "source": 3}, {"type": 4, "value": 8, "source": 1}]
  }
]
```

I don't really have strong preferences on the output format, as long as the information is there and grouped correctly, so for example this would be fine too:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01", "data": [{"type": 1, "value": 10, "source": 2}, {"type": 2, "value": 20, "source": 2}]
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-02", "data": [{"type": 1, "value": 5, "source": 4}, {"type": 2, "value": 6, "source": 3}, {"type": 5, "value": 4, "source": 3}, {"type": 4, "value": 8, "source": 1}]
  }
]
```

Or this (which I guess would require casting `type` to string, which is not a problem):

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01", "1": {"value": 10, "source": 2}, "2": {"value": 20, "source": 2}
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-02", "1": {"value": 5, "source": 4}, "2": {"value": 6, "source": 3}, "5": {"value": 4, "source": 3}, "4": {"value": 8, "source": 1}
  }
]
```

Even this, as long as the field ordering is known in advance:

```
[
  {
    "2020-01-01": [[1, 10, 2], [2, 20, 2]]
  },
  {
    "2020-01-02": [[1, 5, 4], [2, 6, 3], [5, 4, 3], [4, 8, 1]]
  }
]
```

In short, whatever is easiest/most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT "timestamp", json_agg(json_build_object('type', "type", 
                                                   'value', "value",
                                                   'source', "source")) intermediate_json
    FROM test
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object("timestamp", intermediate_json)) final_json
FROM cte
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2fc37233058437189b8e0a8eea05a01b

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!